# iOS not able to upload images to server on Mobile Data/4G network where in Wifi it is working fine

Tags: ios, networking, timeout, nsurlsession, image-upload

I am using NSURLSesssion upload task to upload images to server, sending in bytes. It is working fine in wifi, but when I upload using MobileData/4G LTE network it shows -1001 error code.

I tried:

1. Increased server side timeout to 4 minutes.
2. Tried with small kb size image.

Still, the issue exists only on 4G LTE networks.

Note: The same service API works in Android.

Please let me know what can the issue be?

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
[request setCachePolicy:cachePolicy];
[self prepareMethod:methodURL methodType:methodType dataInBody:dataInBody contentType:contentType withRequest:request];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData * bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

params = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userparams"]mutableCopy];

for (NSString *param in params)
{
    if (![param isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}

// add image data
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpeg\"\r\n", @"file"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[params objectForKey:@"file"]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
// sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120.0;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionUploadTask* uploadtask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:bodyData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

  if (!error)
  {
      NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
      HttpResponse * response = [[HttpResponse alloc] initWithHttpURLResponse:httpResponse withData:data];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionFinishedLoading:)]) {
              [delegate connectionFinishedLoading:response];
          }
      });

  }
  else
  {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionFailedWithError:)])
          {
              [delegate connectionFailedWithError:error];
          }
      });
  }


}];
[uploadtask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

1001 is a timeout.  This could mean that your cellular connection sucks or that your test host isn't reachable from the cellular network.

That said, you're also using a foreground session (the default session) to upload a huge chunk of data, and as soon as your app gets backgrounded or the phone powers down to save power, that connection is going to get canceled.  You almost certainly should be using a background session that you create.  That way, your uploads don't get canceled.

Also, uploading large files over cellular is generally a bad idea, because the HTTP spec doesn't provide support for resuming an upload when the network glitches.  If a file takes more than about five seconds to upload on average, you should make changes to the server side so that you can upload that file in multiple chunks and reassemble it afterwards.